# Gtk::ScrolledWindow disable scroll to focused child

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

I have a very big `Gtk::EventBox` in a `Gtk::ScrolledWindow`.
The moment I do `grab_focus()` at my `Gtk::EventBox`,
the `Gtk::ScrolledWindow` scrolls to the top of the `Gtk::EventBox`.

How can I disable this behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Gtk::EventBox` does not inherit `Gtk::Scrollable`
and therefor gets wrapped with a `Gtk::Viewport`
when it gets added to a `Gtk::ScrolledWindow`.

To disable scroll to focused child you need to change the `focus_hadjustment`/`focus_vadjustment`

```
//Disable scroll to focused child
auto viewport = dynamic_cast<Gtk::Viewport*>(m_scrolled.get_child());
if (viewport) {
  auto dummy_adj = Gtk::Adjustment::create(0,0,0);
  viewport->set_focus_hadjustment(dummy_adj);
  viewport->set_focus_vadjustment(dummy_adj);
}
```